# Scrollify allowing small movements between slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I've implemented Scrollify in a page I'm building - but it's allowing little micromovements between the slides instead of snapping properly. I'm almost certain the DIV's are being calculated correctly, and understand that it's more designed to work with Sections, but I don't think that's what is happening here.

Secondary to this, the scrolling is unpredictable on iOS - sometimes it refuses to budge.

I'm hoping this is just a small error in my code - but I sure as hell can't find it!

I'm trying to avoid using CSS snap points as I had way more issues with them - this is *almost* perfect.

http://223.252.101.58/~mb/nothing/

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to address the ID problem you have. 
If you look in the console Scrollify is giving you warnings about using IDs that match your hash values.
This will invoke the browsers native anchoring so will interfere with Scrollify's snapping behaviour.

Comment: Hey Luke, thanks for that - it resolved a lot of issues but it's still not quite there - a lot closer though! Thankyou!

Comment: I found that there was a secondary issue with another script item attempting to auto set the heights - this made it better again. Are you able to reproduce the leniancy in the scrolling? It seems like it can overshoot the slide a little - I'm thinking it might be the slide padding, surely not as the sections are placed outside of the Div...

Comment: Think it might relate to how your images are being sized. Experiment by giving them a height of 80%.